# Могут ли инструменты для Visual Studio из маркетплейса воровать мой код?

Tags: visual-studio

Инструменты для VS из маркетплейса не могут ведь как-то претендовать на написанный код или воровать его?

Comment: Это никак не относится к данному разделу. Если и пишите что-то, то подробней. ПО какое по вашему мнение это делает. И как вы определили что код украли/хотят ?

Comment: Инструменты имеют полный доступ к редактору кода, так что если какой-нибудь издатель решит покуситься на Ваш код, его ничто не остановит. Вот только это из разряда "к каждому приставлен свой ФСБшник". Никому Ваш код не сдался